# How to expose ResultSet as JSON/XML via Webservice?

Tags: java, json, xml, resultset

I'm using `spring-mvc` to create a `@RestController` webservice.

Question: how can I expose a `ResultSet` from a sql query via the webservice, as `JSON` or `XML`.

The column names should represent the json/xml field name.

xml: `<col1>myval1<col1>`

json: `"col1": myval1`

Is that simply possible using some apache or spring utility?

Important note: I do not want to map the sql result to a pojo `bean` with getters and setters before. I just want to expose the results without converting to a predefined bean before.

Like php supports it using `json_encode(rows)`.

---

**Update:** I cannot post a solution as the question is locked, but I found a neat way achieving the result with spring:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).queryForList(..);
```

You then can just return this `List` as response via a `@RequestMapping` method inside `@RestController`.
Spring will take care of the rest and marshal it as requested, eg as JSON or XML.

No need to write custom converters to json objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://biercoff.com/nice-and-simple-converter-of-java-resultset-into-jsonarray-or-xml/) for your solution . Hope this will help you.

Comment: So there is no buildin or framework solution? Like php supports it out of the box

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.